# Configure DeepLearning4J to work with MKL (instead of OpenBlas)

Tags: deeplearning4j

I'm using word2vec with DL4J (DeepLearning4J).
When running the application, I see that the application always loads [OPENBLAS]. I can see this log entry:

```
INFO [main] DefaultOpExecutioner - Blas vendor: [OPENBLAS]
```

How can I configure it to load [MKL] instead?
I have MKL installed and running on Windows.

Comment: What version of dl4j are you using?

Comment: Make sure that the system properties described here are set: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/tree/master/openblas#documentation

Answer (score 0):

As Samuel said, need to define a system variable in order to load MKL.
Specifically, this worked for me:

```
-Dorg.bytedeco.openblas.load=mklml
```

`-Dorg.bytedeco.openblas.load=mkl_rt`

More info in: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/tree/master/openblas#documentation